# Struggling with Play.current.configuration.getStringList("mongodb.replicaSetSeeds") Option handling

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.5

I have an conf/application.conf setting like

```
mongodb.replicaSetSeeds = ["bobk-mbp.local:27017","bobk-mbp.local:27018"]
```

I'm pulling it out in my code like (the actual extraction is a little different, but this is the gist of it)

```
val replicaSetSeeds = Play.current.configuration.getStringList("mongodb.replicaSetSeeds")
val listOfString: List[String] = replicaSetSeeds.getOrElse(List("localhost"))
```

but the compiler hates me

```
type mismatch;  found   : Object  required: List[String]
```

The signature of getStringList is

```
def getStringList(path: String): Option[java.util.List[String]]
```

How do I handle the None case here or is my problem List[String] is not the same as List[java.util.String]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
val optList:Option[List[String]] = Play.current.configuration.getStringList("mongodb.replicaSetSeeds").map(_.toList)
val list = optList.getOrElse(List("localhost"))
```

There are multiple things going on here.  First, you need to import the `JavaConversions` implicits because what's being returned is an `Option[java.util.List[String]]` and we want that to be a scala `List` instead.  By doing the `map(_.toList)`, I'm forcing the implicit conversion to kick in and get me an `Option[List[String]]` and from there things are pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

In play 2.5, you need to use dependency injection, the following works well for me:

1) in your class inject `Configuration`

```
class Application @Inject()(
  configuration: play.api.Configuration
) ...
```

2) in your method

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val optlist = configuration.getStringList("mongodb.replicaSetSeeds").map{_.toList}
val list = optList.getOrElse(List("localhost"))
```